# Аналог fread для fstream или как грамотно считать заголовок bmp-файла в структуру?

Tags: c++, структуры, io, bmp

Дано: для работы(считывания/записи) c bmp используется fstream. Вопрос в следующем: есть ли для fstream удобный способ считывания заголовка файла в структуру (типа как fread для FILE, который считывает хедер одним куском и распихивает данные по полям структуры)? 
Структуры заголовков (на всякий случай):

```
typedef struct tagBITMAPFILEHEADER
{
    WORD    bfType; 
    DWORD   bfSize; 
    WORD    bfReserved1; 
    WORD    bfReserved2; 
    DWORD   bfOffBits; 
} __attribute__((packed)) BITMAPFILEHEADER;

typedef struct tagBITMAPINFOHEADER
{
    DWORD    biSize; 
    LONG     biWidth; 
    LONG     biHeight; 
    WORD     biPlanes; 
    WORD     biBitCount; 
    DWORD    biCompress; 
    DWORD    biSizeImage; 
    LONG     biXPelsPerMeter; 
    LONG     biYPelsPerMeter; 
    DWORD    biClrUsed; 
    DWORD    biClrImportant; 
} __attribute__((packed)) BITMAPINFOHEADER;
```

Пример кода:

```
int main() {
    BITMAPFILEHEADER file_header;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER info_header;
    fstream image("Bmp.bmp", ios::in | ios::binary);
    image.read((char*)&file_header, sizeof(file_header));
    image.read((char*)&info_header, sizeof(info_header));

    // вычисление количества добавочных бит
    size_t padding = 0;
    if ((info_header.biWidth * 3) % 4) {
      padding = static_cast<size_t>(4 - (info_header.biWidth * 3) % 4);
    }

    char ** rubish = new char*[info_header.biHeight];

    // cчитывание данных картинки
    rgb = new RGBTRIPLE *[info_header.biHeight];
    for (int i = 0; i < info_header.biHeight; i++) {
        rgb[i] = new RGBTRIPLE[info_header.biWidth];
        image.read((char *)&rgb[i], sizeof(rgb[i]));

        if (padding != 0) {
            rubish[i] = new char[padding];
            image.read((char *) &rubish[i], sizeof(rubish[i]));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Структура RGBTRIPLE:

```
typedef struct tagRGBTRIPLE {
    BYTE    rgbtBlue;
    BYTE    rgbtGreen;
    BYTE    rgbtRed;
} RGBTRIPLE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Для такого чтения открывать `fstream` следует в бинарном режиме (`ios::binary`), а для чтения-записи использовать функции [`read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read)/[`write`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write).

Естественно, разговор идет о чтении структур POD (plain old data), без каких-либо указателей или хитрых объектов классов типа `string`.

Comment: Меня просто смущает в этих функциях каст к char*. Это нормально, что будет сделан каст структуры к указателю на char?

Comment: иными словами, корректно ли это: image.read((char*)&file_header, sizeof(file_header));
image.read((char*)&info_header, sizeof(info_header));

Comment: @Nabla Да, это разрешено.

Comment: Проблема в том, что если я использую такой  синтаксис, то структура ничем не заполняется(в полях остаются нули). В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Приведите минимальный компилируемый пример, pls...

Comment: Не знаю, о чем говорю, но - img и image? Открываем одно, читаем другое?

Comment: Да, мой косяк. Я хреново перекопировал на сайт.

Comment: С заголовками разобраться удалось. Как теперь сделать так, чтобы нормально считать данные в массив структур с помощью данных функций?

Comment: Дебагировать. Т.е. в первую очередь проверять, не возвращают ли эти методы ошибку. Скорее всего возвращают, а вы не видите.

Comment: is_open() используйте, файл может и не открылся, тогда всё последующее уже нет смысла смотреть..